# Debug a bad DLL calling convention

Tags: vba, ms-access, dll

How do I debug a bad DLL calling convention error in MSAccess VBA code?

I made some changes to a function in a module and then got the error. How do a debug it to find the cause?

The error occurs on the Exit function statement of the function.

Comment: You're calling a native function declared with the "Declare" statement, right? Could you share both the declaration and the call with us?

Comment: I fixed it...all i had to do is start access with /decompile and then recompile and the error went away.

Comment: For resolutions to this error in Excel, see my post at: [Runtime Error 49, Bad DLL calling convention][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758834/runtime-error-49-bad-dll-calling-convention

Comment: This worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720241/4836581

Answer (score 30):

I fixed this problem by making a change in one of my class modules, executing a compilation from the Debug menu, and then undoing the change.

**Background**: In my case I've seen this in Excel without any external references. It happened, as with your problem, on an Exit Function call. Excel doesn't seem to have a /decompile option. I suspect that one of my class modules had mis-compiled for some reason, and Excel won't re-compile unless it thinks something has changed.

Comment: Holy f* thanks for posting this, exact problem I had.  I just placed an xxxx at the top of every module, then: Debug, Compile VBAProject (which will highlight a xxxx)...delete that --> Debug, Compile VBAProject...repeat until no more compile errors.

Comment: Sometimes a small change is not enough, because VBA does an incremental compilation and the small changes may not trigger the re-compilation of the corrupted area. A select all/cut/paste on each module usually does the trick

Comment: @Jon-artus I rearanged your sentences. I believe that it highlights the fix better but if you feel otherwise don't hesitate to revert

Answer (score 20):

Have you checked your references and decompiled?

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" 
                                "d:\My Documents\access\mayapp.mdb" /decompile
```

See also: 
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm 
[VBScript Decompile](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Decompile)

---

Check references in code

```
Dim ref As Reference
Dim sMsg As String

''Available since 2010
If BrokenReference Then
    For Each ref In References
        ''Available since at least 2000
        If ref.IsBroken Then
            sMsg = sMsg & "Ref Name: " & ref.Name
            'Also, if required
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "Built In: " & ref.BuiltIn
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "Full Path: " & ref.FullPath
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "GUID: " & ref.Guid
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "Kind: " & ref.Kind
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "Major (version number): " & ref.Major
            'sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "Minor (version number): " & ref.Minor
            sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & "=================================" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox sMsg
End If
```

Comment: I ran into this error on a call (and again on return from function) to an Access VBA function I'd written - not an external API function.  /decompile and recompile did the trick.
I suspect that a lot of debugging (rather than just running) a recursive function got Access confused, and /decompile cleaned up the mess.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced and worked around this error using [the .NET library for WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_vb#example) from MS Access VBA.

What happened was:

1. A function `UploadSomething` for connecting to an SFTP server and uploading a file worked fine.
2. Within the function `UploadSomething` changed the "resume support" option with this code: `myTransferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.TransferResumeSupportState_Off`

After the change, the code worked as desired. However in the code that *called* `UploadSomething`, Error 49 was thrown after the function had finished.

The error happened both when stepping through the code using the debugger and when executing at once outside of the debugger. Recompiling the project didn't work for me.

What did work was this:

1. Remove the reference to the COM component
2. Add the reference to the COM component
3. Recompile

Answer (score 1):

In Excel VBA, this can be caused by any of several problems:

1. A parameter or return-value type mismatch.
2. An object method (such as AutoFit) applied to an erroneous object
   variation for which that method isn’t available.
3. A call to an external library function.
4. Broken library references

For resolutions to these causes, see my post at: [Runtime Error 49, Bad DLL calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758834/runtime-error-49-bad-dll-calling-convention)

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this in Excel and wondered if anyone else have gotten it previously. My solution was to move around the references to my own DLL and click 'Compile <Project>'.

Answer (score 0):

We've run into some problems with VBA when trying to call a DLL compiled in Intel Fortran.  It turns out that you need to align the calling conventions back to a "C" context with the compiler flag ***calling convention: cfv***

More info here on the [Intel website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/298583)
Another useful thread on the same problem: [Intel Fortran DLL <-> C](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/276310)