# Access 2013: Recurring error: Return without Gosub

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

so I am building a database and I always keep getting a recurring error 'return without goSub'. It is very frustrating and I really want to get rid of it for once and for all.

The error itself occurs on a form and where clicking a button would go to another form, this time it displays the error message.

I usually 'fix' this issue by copying and pasting everything to a new database.

This error has occured on the front end of a split database, hence I am worried the above solution would not work.

Can anyone suggest how I can go about solving this?

compiling also does not work.

I don't know if it's a problem with the primary key or relationships.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Different Access version, but this post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467746/return-without-gosub-when-using-subforms-in-access

Comment: I've tried and tested that method, Darren but it does not help me. Please advise if there's any other solution thanks!