# Missing DateSerial reference?

Tags: ms-access

Has anyone ever come across the following error in MS Access? This is MS Access 2007 - 2010...

Undefined function "DateSerial" in expression?

The query is like this:

```
TheDate: DateSerial(CInt([TABLE_BIRTH]![BIRTH_YEAR]),CInt([TABLE_BIRTH]![BIRTH_MONTH]),CInt([TABLE_BIRTH]![BIRTH_DAY]))
```

I double checked the query by simplifying it as DateSerial(2010,10,01) and it reports the error.

I suspect the problem is that the reference is missing somehow but I checked the VBA references and nothing is reported as missing.

I searched the object browser and found it in the member of DateTime class...

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have decompiled and compacted and repaired yesno?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574587/debug-a-bad-dll-calling-convention-error-in-msaccess-vba-code/683399#683399

Comment: If things are still a bit weird, you can import everything into a clean database. You might like to read http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm