# Excel VBA: "Run-time error '49': Bad DLL calling convention" calling C++ dll

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I am attempting to call a C++ DLL from Excel-VBA.

I know the DLL function is being executed as I inserted fputs() logging calls to track execution and the stamps are showing up in my log file. The problem is, whenever the DLL function returns, I get Error 49.

Here is the declaration in VBA:

```
Private Declare Function InitMCR Lib "MCRBoilerplate.dll" Alias "?initMCR@@YGXXZ" ()
```

and here is the declaration in C++

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall initMCR() { ... }
```

Why am I getting this Error 49 behavior, even though the DLL calls appear to be working?

Comment: OK, I seem to have misinterpreted your 1st version too early not being a valid question. Now I see, you wanted to provide another Q&A by giving the solution. I'd recommend you put your solution part as an answer to the question. You can do so here, it's valid and encouraged.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer

Comment: @wgrant /OT Note: You don't need to click `save` to get intermediate versions of your edits backed up here (SO backs up your drafts while you're editing after a certain time). As soon you click `save`, you're publishing your stuff, and you may receive downvotes and critique about your actually unfinished stuff. Sorry for the initial down/close votes, you're welcome in general. Put your solution as an answer as suggested, and I'd even upvote both of it.

Comment: @david-heffernan Nice action, but my initial intention was to get the OP learning s.th. about how the site works. You're right, I should have been clarifying using another comment (did so now).

Comment: Thanks for the insight everyone. I had intended to provide the answer immediately as @Niall and πάντα ῥεῖ suggested but since I had less than 10 rep, SO made me wait 24 hours before posting an answer. You guys beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, functions that return `void` need to be declared as `Sub` instead of `Function`

So the declaration in VBA should be:

```
Private Declare Sub InitMCR Lib "MCRBoilerplate.dll" Alias "?initMCR@@YGXXZ" ()
```

See [MSDN page on VBA Declare statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278581%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A quick point: your problem might not be a parameter mismatch in your external function, or in the declaration that imports it - there's a known compiler glitch in VBA that raises error 49.

['Stacker pstraton's answer to 'Excel - Runtime Error 49: Bad DLL calling convention'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758834/runtime-error-49-bad-dll-calling-convention)

You're not completely blameless - you probably have a parameter mismatch with a returned type that *should* work (Long populating an Int, Variants populating just about anything) in the calling function - but I have never heard of anyone banishing a persistent Runtime Error 49 by better coding. You just recompile, or export and reimport the modules.

The worst of it is that a *genuine* Forty-Niner is far harder to debug than it needs to be: the statement that triggers the error message usually isn't a call to the misdeclared external function. If you're lucky, it's the 'Exit Sub' of the caller; and some of the time it's something further up the stack that you can trace back to the bad call; but, sometimes, it isn't obvious at all and there's no deterministic debugging strategy at all.