# Import DLL Function VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have compiled a DLL from a C++ Library I have written according to [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The dumpbin for the dll is as follows:

```
  Section contains the following exports for HelloDLL.dll
    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           6 number of functions
           6 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011032 ?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z = @ILT+45(?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
          2    1 00011037 ?AddMultiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z = @ILT+50(?AddMultiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
          3    2 000112EE ?Multiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z = @ILT+745(?Multiply@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z)
          4    3 000110F5 Add = @ILT+240(_Add)
          5    4 00011073 AddMultiply = @ILT+110(_AddMultiply)
          6    5 0001105F Multiply = @ILT+90(_Multiply)
```

Now I want to use the Functions in an Excel-VBA Project like this:

```
Declare Function LIB_AddMultiply Lib "C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\HelloDLL\Debug\HelloDLL.dll" Alias "AddMultiply" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double

Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    a = 3
    b = 4
    Dim c As Double
    c = LIB_AddMultiply(a, b)
    MsgBox ("hi " + c)
End Sub
```

But whenever I want to run the `test()` I get a `Bad DLL Calling convention; Error 49`.

I already looked at the following (and some other) resources, but couldn't resolve my problem:

- [Runtime Error 49, Bad DLL calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758834/runtime-error-49-bad-dll-calling-convention/25943994)
- [Error 49](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/bad-dll-calling-convention-error-49?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1000049)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)
- [Declare Statement MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declare-statement)

Do you have any advice?

Thanks a lot...

**UPDATE:**

This is the code for the header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#endif  

namespace MathLibrary
{
    class Functions
    {
    public:
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double Add(double a, double b);
        //[...]
    };

    extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return MathLibrary::Functions::Add(a, b);
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: These functions are being compiled as `__cdecl`, the default for C++ code.  Not compatible with VBA.  The easiest way to do this for a DLL that you designed to be used from VBA is to change the default.  Project > Properties > Configuration combobox = All > C/C++ > Advanced > "Calling convention" = stdcall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Hans Passant for your help;

I have changed the project properties to the calling convention;
then did another dumpbin with the result of my Functions being named as

```
_Add@16
```

and then just changed the Alias in the VBA code...